# GSSAPI Docker Installation Issue - /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found

Tags: python, kerberos, gssapi

I successfully tried out GSSAPI to generate kerberos tickets in my Python app locally on my Mac.  Now I am trying to package this as a Docker image.

When I try to build the image I keep getting this error:

```
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 > [ 6/13] RUN pip install gssapi:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#10 1.307 Collecting gssapi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#10 1.383   Downloading gssapi-1.8.2.tar.gz (94 kB)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#10 1.400      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 94.3/94.3 kB 6.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00                                                                                                                                                                   
#10 1.427   Installing build dependencies: started                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#10 4.102   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#10 4.103   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#10 4.548   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
#10 4.552   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 4.552   
#10 4.552   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#10 4.552   │ exit code: 1
#10 4.552   ╰─> [25 lines of output]
#10 4.552       /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
#10 4.552       Traceback (most recent call last):
#10 4.552         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/si
```

I am also running this before I call RUN pip install gssapi:

```
> RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y krb5-config krb5-user
```

The main issue I am trying to solve is this:

```
/bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
```

Docker file:

> FROM python:slim-buster
>
> PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1s
>
> PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
>
> COPY requirements.txt . COPY *.py . RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip RUN apt-get -qq update && 
> apt-get -yqq install krb5-user libpam-krb5 && 
> apt-get -yqq clean \ RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y krb5-config krb5-user RUN pip install gssapi RUN python -m
> pip install -r requirements.txt RUN apt update -y && apt install g++
> -y && apt install build-essential -y && apt install unixodbc-dev -y RUN apt install -y libgssapi-krb5-2 && apt install curl -y RUN curl
> https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - RUN
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list >
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list RUN apt update -y &&
> ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get
> install -y mssql-tools18 RUN echo 'export
> PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
>
> CMD ["python","main.py"]

What am I missing?  I can't seem to find anything on this.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this is also required before gssapi is installed:

apt-get install libkrb5-dev -y